How to extract data from chess pdf file?
I was trying to copy some lines from chess opening book pdf to chess engine, to see if the lines are still relevant, or refuted by newer engines. However, it wasn't really in standard algebraic notation, as it uses piece icons instead of their first letters. Those icons are still copy-able, but result in semi random letter combinations that engine doesn't recognize. Am I forced to use some OCR software to extract such data, or is there a method for decoding it? I guessed that pdf used some type of embedded font that my pc does not have, but it isn't really consistent. For example, knight (N) is copied as "liJ" in only about 50 times per 300 page book, so it's difficult to create some lookup replacement table.

"find some extractable pattern in a PDF you cannot see and which may be inconsistent" does not seem like a great setup for useful answers. On the remote chance that this is an established pattern for chess PDFs that someone will recognize, they would still have to guess from your one example. Is there a chance you could make this more practical/reduce the guesswork? Larger sample? Share the file?

FYI, that sounds like what's called figuring algebraic notation.
